# Full bridge rectifier for a 5 ns pulse

Tags: diodes, bridge-rectifier

I want to build a system to measure the time of flight for a long transmission line. The length of the transmission line is between 500 m and 3 km. The attenuation of the transmission line is 0.00981 dB/m. The impedance of the transmission line is 150 ohm. A 3 V pulse fed into a 3 km long transmission line will lead to a reflection with an amplitude of 100 mV.
I want to measure the time of flight. From previous measurements I know that the signal needs 1 ns to travel 20 cm.

My goal is to determine the length of the transmission line with a accuracy of 10 m.

My approach is to drive the transmission line with a high current output opamp, that outputs a 5 ns pulse with an amplitude of 3 V. Since the signal will be attenuated along the way, I am using a VGA (variable gain amplifier) to amplify the signal to around 3 V, so it can be read by a µController.
Infront of the VGA I am planning to place a Bandpass filter, to get rid of the noise floor and possible DC offsets. The passband will be from 200 MHz (1/5ns) to 2 GHz. I know that the bandpass filter will lead to a decrease in accuracy since the edges will become less "sharp" but thats negligible.
Infront of the VGA I placed a comparator to prevent switching uncertainties.

[image]

My problem now is:

The reflected pulse can either have a positive or a negative polarity, depending if the transmission lines end is short circuit or open end.

So I am trying to detect a pulse with a width of 5 ns that can have a negative polarity (short circuit at the end of the transmission line) but also a positive polarity (open end transmission line). The pulse occurs every 30 seconds. The voltage is 3 V, the current is 100 mA max.

What is the best way to detect this pulse with the best accuracy possible?

Comment: 30 seconds is irrelevant. Take a look at a datasheet for RF Schottkys and do some simulations. 30 V and 5 ns is going to be a big challenge.

Comment: @winny it is 3V and 5ns. Maybe I should use opamps as a full bridge rectifier?

Comment: Sorry, I misread that. 3 V and 5 ns is going to be challenging but possible. Take a look at HSMS-282x.

Comment: uff, a pulse with a width of 5ns has probably steep edges (edge time < 1ns?), and so you're looking at something with a high bandwidth. Something like that is most of the time AC-coupled, anyway, so, um, for what specifically do you need that polarity?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want to feed it into a comparator than into a µController, so it has to be positive. edge time is around 1ns, yes. 
And yes it is AC coupled. Do you know any other way to succesfully convert it into a positive signal?

Comment: but if you feed it into a comparator, just swap the inputs?!

Comment: Op amps are not the answer; you flat out cannot get an op amp fast enough for this kind of application. You want to just use diodes, but use very very fast diodes. That means Schottkys, even FREDs will be too slow.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but the signal pulse I am talking about is not always negative, it is also positive sometimes. I want it to be positive all the time. If I swap the inputs and the pulse is positive the pulse will become negative

Comment: OK, now it's getting confusing. Could you **edit** your question and describe your overall system? This feels a lot like you're trying to build a receiver for some specific differential signalling standard that was almost certainly designed with some specific receiver in mind, but you're trying to (suboptimally) re-invent the wheel.

Comment: @Hearth at which parameters should I be looking at inside the schottky diode datasheets?

Comment: @MarcusMüller it is for a flight of time circuit (see edit), this pulse can be positive or negative depending on the end of the transmission line

Comment: It may be easier to set up two detectors, one for positive and one for negative pulses.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis how can I detect a negative pulse? I still need to make it positive or not

Comment: I'd have to know more about your detector to answer that.  For instance, if it's differential, you could hook up the leads the opposite way.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis it is single ended, I could simply feed the pulse into two comparators, one with swapped inputs, right?

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis but then how do I get rid of the one negative voltage that is output by one comparator?

Comment: @Hearth how is a fast diode defined?

Comment: @Yoomo a fast diode is defined as "fast enough to deal with your signal": you'll need to read *datasheets*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller but what is the parameter I am looking for? Recovery time?

Comment: That, and capacity in the voltage range you care about. Not all diodes have the same datasheets - some will actually have behavioural parameters plotted against frequency and so on.

Comment: @MarcusMüller why does the diodes capacity matter?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I found this product brief https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-RF+Schottky+Diodes-PB-v01_01-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462557e6e890155917b964163fb this looks really promising it says it can handle frequencies till 24GHz and has low capacitance. I am considering to use the BAT68, the reverse voltage is over 3V and it also has a low forward voltage of 318mV at 1mA

Comment: you're solving a problem you have not fully stated. I'm **really** not convinced your bridge rectifier approach goes in any sensible direction, honestly. You don't need a bridge rectifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fU5fQG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

should do it.

Idea: an XOR is 0 when both inputs are the same, and 1 when they are different. XNOR inverts that: 1 if both are same, 0 if the inputs are different.

Since your input is AC coupled, as long as nothing happens, the upper input of the below circuit is at VCC · 3/4, and the lower one is at VCC · 1/4, so, one is high, the other low, and the output is 0.

When you get a positive pulse, it shifts the already positive input further up, so that input stays high, but it also shifts the lower input up, so it becomes high; now, both inputs are the same, and the XNOR outputs a 1.

When you get a negative pulse, that shifts your upper input down, so you get a low input on your upper input, and the lower input becomes even lower, so stays low. Both inputs are now low, XNOR outputs a 1.

Note that this relies on the protection diodes of your XNOR gate to deal with a bit of overvoltage, and undervoltage. Very often, that's not a problem. If it becomes a problem, a USB3 ESD diode array might be used to add needed protection.

It also relies on the signal level being high enough to shift these inputs – but the required sensitivity can be achieved through adjusting the resistor values.

Comment: the problem with a XNOR gate is that the propagation delay is really high

Comment: a) define "really high": I bet you're just looking at an old XNOR gate. Also, even if it were: b) that's not a problem at all. You don't need low propagation delay. In fact, you don't *care* about delay, at all: It's just a fixed delay that you need to subtract, just as you need to subtract the group delay through the rest of your circuitry. So, that's not even an extra step during calibration.

Comment: I looked up XNOR gates with the lowest delay on mouser, the lowest delay was 25ns. The delay is also dependent on the temperature. Lets say the delay at 25°C is 25ns, how big is the delay at 40°C?

Comment: yeah, I don't know how you've found that, but three clicks on TI.com led me to XOR gates with < 5 ns delay, and since you can use an XOR gate as inverter, that means you can build a < 10 ns XNOR out of these. So, indeed, you're looking at old technology. Anyway, you're still very right - the moment your calibration needs to incorporate temperature, things get complicated. How well can you control the temperature of the cable under test? Because, you don't need to make your measurement device better temperature-controller or -compensated than you can control your tested object.

Comment: Anyway, the datasheets of these higher-speed XOR gates do specifiy the delay range over the whole operating temperature range (e.g. the SN74AUC2G86 datasheet says it's 0.3 ns to 1.3 ns – which means that you calibrate once, and then have a sensor that says "sorry, temperature of measurement device outside 15–40° C, performance degraded", and probably get some 0.1 ns accuracy... Compare that to the *immense* uncertainty that you'd get with an uncompensated diode bridge. **Maybe** you should start your questions by stating the requirements you have before discussing an option to achieve them!

Comment: A pulse with a rise time of 1 ns anyway limits the resolution, no matter what you do – there's simple thermal noise bounds you don't get around.

Comment: thank you for your insights, really helpful like always! I am planing to build two different prototypes, one with the diode bridge and one with the XNOR and test them both. And what do you mean with uncompensated? I don't really know the drawbacks of a diode bridge in this application

Comment: since the XNOR is a digital gate I will have to place it after the comparator, right? Probably a dumb question

Comment: there's no comparator involved. arggggh, the whole point of my answer was to explain what you do to detect the pulse - without using a comparator. I must have written it really terribly...

Comment: no I am sorry, I am not the brightest candle on the cake. So I can just feed the analog signal into this XNOR gate?

Comment: literally, everything in my answer after "idea:" explains that.

Comment: ok I will just feed the analog signal into the XNOR and see what happens. Thank you

Comment: I'll repeat what I've recommended above: ask question, but make sure you describe your overall system **and the requirements** of what you need to achieve. I can't say whether any specific approach will work for you – simply because you've never stated **any** constraints, it's always just aspects that we have to pick out of post-fact discussions with you. That's not how you get competent help! **State the problem before describing a solution** is always the right way in engineering. You won't get anywhere here just throwing together components that you don't fully understand.

Comment: I tried my best describing the problem, really. Its a time of flight circuit I want to detect the signal that is reflected at the end of the transmission line.

Comment: I looked inside the TI XOR, XNOR datasheets, most of them have a schmitt trigger input, which is good to prevent switching uncertainties. So I definetly don't need a comparator infront of the gate

Comment: Yoomo, it really shows you don't *understand*, what you're doing here.

Comment: I think I do understand

Comment: I think you should really ask a question that is roughly like "I want to build a {what you want to build}. The critical specs are: root mean square accuracy of ..., over a range of .... My current approach is …. How do I do … to achieve …?". All your questions are "How do I…?" without stating any of your goals, and you really get lost in details without having finalized an understanding of the overall system.

Comment: I described my problem as you said. I hope you are satisfied now

Comment: Wow, thanks! Yeah, that's much better!

Comment: @MarucsMüller I hope you understand my concerns know with the analog signal. I don't think it is the right way to just place the XNOR instead of the comparator. I think placing it behind the comparator would be better since the XNOR is a digital gate

Comment: you're still not understanding what a comparator and what this gate is, but that doesn't matter. There's no such thing as "digital" here: all these things react to analogue signals, all signals are analog. "digital" might be an application.

Comment: excuse me, the comparator I was describing should be a schmitt trigger to prevent switching uncertainties. Anyway I will be using the XNOR gates instead of the schmitt trigger, since they already have a schmitt trigger input build into them

Comment: no, that's not what you need. again.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that the signal needs 1ns to travel 20cm.

$$\frac{20\,\text{cm}}{1\,\text{ns}}=\frac{2\cdot10^{-1}\,\text{m}}{10^{-9}\,\text{s}}=2\cdot10^8\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}$$

just as expected from a transmission line, roughly 2/3 of the vacuum speed of light. However: this has at most **two** significant digits, i.e. you get at least 1% of error if your speed measurements aren't accurate. You want 10m accuracy over 3 km, that's 0.033% of error.

Measuring your signal speed accurately makes or breaks your whole measurement.

> My goal is to determine the length of the transmission line with a accuracy of 10m.

So, you need to measure timing to an accuracy of **50 ns**! (and you were complaining about logic gates with a few ns of delay uncertainty...)

> 500m and 3km

So, rundtrip times of 2.5 µs to 15 µs.

OK, this gives us a lot to work off!

> drive the transmission line with a high current output opamp, that outputs a 5ns pulse with an amplitude of 3V.

Oh! I wouldn't recommend that; totally wrong. An opamp is useful if you need something that amplifies the input nice and linearly. You don't want that. You want the sharpest edge you can get.

So, opamp: would need fantastic (significantly more than 1GHz!) bandwidth.

Instead, a simple CMOS push-pull stage with a MOSFET driver will give you an excellent sharp edge.

You will want to add a 150Ω series resistor to match the impedance of your MOSFETs (which will be very low) to the transmission line.

The duration of the pulse doesn't matter, by the way, for your system. What matters is the steepness of its edges. (Which are inverse to its bandwidth.)
You can measure the distance just as accurately with a 20s duration pulse as with a 5ns pulse, as long as the bandwidth of the edges are the same!

> I am planning to place a Bandpass filter

Excellent!

A band-pass filter filters away low frequencies. If you design it such that the lower cut-off frequency is above 1/(pulse duration), then you get something that resembles the *derivative* of your pulse. Instead of seeing a rising and a falling edge, you get two pulses where the edges are!

Read this carefully, and make yourself a drawing of voltage over frequency! Draw a pulse (with slightly round edges, ca 1ns wide, 5ns long pulse), and then, same size, draw the derivative of that function.

That derivative plot should now be a figure with two pulses, one when the rising edge of the original pulse is, one when the falling edge of the original pulse is.

Now, do the same thing, but for an inverted pulse: Now you get one pulse, negative, for the first edge, and one, positive, pulse for the second edge.

See what I'm doing here?

**The highpass part of your bandpass filter just converted your positive and negative pulses into a signal where there's always a positive pulse**.

So, you don't need a rectifier at all. **Forget the rectifier**! It makes things harder, and doesn't help you at all!

Great, now you only have to detect that pulse. A high-speed comparator might indeed do that. But with *a single NPN transistor* you can do the same: since this is all AC-coupled, your pulses are around any arbitrary DC voltage you choose.

So, a single transistor can be used to amplify your signal enough so that it can be directly observed by your microcontroller.

---

So, there we go, your whole system would then be:

- microcontroller to generate the pulse
- a CMOS pair to buffer the pulse and feed it into the transmission line through a 150Ω resistor
- a bandpass filter to convert the pulse into two pulses at the edges
- three resistors and a 10ct NPN with enough bandwidth
- your microcontroller to observe the amplified positive pulse

That's it! No opamps, no comparators, no rectifiers, no logic involved here – just very basic signal theory and *using the right amplifier for the job*.

Comment: thank you, really good ideas. But the NPN transistor has to amplify the signal to 3V, so it can be observed by the µController. The pulse comes with different voltages depending on the length of the transmission line. I would need to design a automatic gain control for this, right?

Comment: no, not right. Why would you? That thing needs to saturate to the microcontroller's IO voltage, that's all. Also, you *literally* have less than 10 dB of dynamic range. So, a single transistor, it is.

Comment: ah ok, so it outputs always the IO voltage when its saturated to the µcontrollers IO Voltage

Comment: you suggested me to drive the transmission line with a CMOS push pull stage and a MOSFET driver. So I will need 3 MOSFETS in total. Why do I need that additional MOSFET driver, isn't the push pull stage enough? Do I need to consider something special when choosing the MOSFET? I think I just need a high current output to overcome the capacitance of the line

Comment: isn't the push pull stage enough to drive the line?